# Can my training and testing data for neural network be of different lengths?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am trying to use a **recurrent neural network** for a **regression** problem. I have 50 samples of 600 `timesteps` each. I am planning to use 40 for training and 10 for validation. 
After my network gets trained, can I use it to predict for a timeseries of a smaller length (200 timesteps)?

The input and output dimensions (i.e. features) will remain same, just the length (i.e. number of timesteps) is smaller

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: How to do it? I am getting error like expected 600 but got 200

Comment: You can pad your data with 400 default value such as `0`, but there is no guarantee that the results would be reasonable.

Comment: @stormzhouso 0 in all input features you mean? And should I give some dummy samples of 600 timesteps with 400 0 values and 200 real values for training?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- First option, as @stormzhou commented above, you can pad you test data with zeros (not recommended)
- Second option, you can use for training and validation only 200 timesteps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to do the second option?

Comment: To be clear, I am NOT doing a 200 timestep ahead prediction. My training set is independent timeseries of 600 timesteps (I have 40 such training samples) and I have to test it on completely independent samples (of the same property, having same number of features) but these samples would be 200 timesteps long.